# Android phone for an outside worker during winter

Tags: smartphones, android

I currently have a Ulefone Armor 11 5G with a 5200 mah battery.  It's about a year old but it's still lightly used.  The problem I am having is, with 4 hours of use it goes down to 20% and it hasn't been that cold too.  Only been around freezing.  Not like 10-25 (centigrade) below the freezing point.

I need to find another phone which is rugged which doesn't really have this problem because I work outside now, basically filling out forms for people.  Sure, for me where I live which is the Midwestern US, it's mild. If curious, the summers with the heat index can get up to 50.  My work relies on me having a charged phone/tablet.  I can not simply just stop to charge it nor can I plug in a battery pack because I have to carry it, I do not sit at a table but walk around and basically interview people.  And that's the problem and newer phones for some gosh damn reason there do not have swappable batteries.  I have nerve damage to my right arm and anything heavy I tend to drop.  So, I drop my phone literally at least on avg 1 time per day and so it needs to withstand that.

Is there anything that is built for winter but wouldn't overheat during the summer and is on the lighter side?  I need it to be charged during the spring and summer because of longer days for at least 14 hours.  Right now, I am basically working from like 11-noon to 4-5 PM on the weekdays, and on the weekends I can basically work from 9-to-9 if I want to.

***Off-topic - What I mean by lightly use**.  I grew up without a smartphone, and so the only time I truly use it is using a program which can only run on Android or when I need to make a call when I am outside.  I have gone on a bicycle tour and other trips for state testing to the state capital without even carrying it.  If I have nothing important for a day and let's say I want to enjoy the day by going outside, then I do not typically carry it because it's just extra weight.  At my previous job, someday I would carry it and some days I would just leave it at home.  I basically only carry it if I have to.  **If curious why.** I just do not find the value in them despite being a power user.  There is very little that I can do on a smartphone, the only thing I can truly think of on a personal level for me is looking at maps, making calls, and that is basically it, minus now you get businesses that only develop for iOS or Android and they can not even make a web application and so they force you into having an smartphone.  I also hate having to deal with the hidden menus because once it took me 50 minutes to figure out how to turn off flash when taking a picture.  I was looking throughout the system settings, the application settings, etc.  It was a hidden swap motion to bring up the menu and I just discovered it by accident through frustration.  A standalone camera is just going to work, a camera on a phone can not compare with the quality of a 50-dollar phone.  I have never found any phone even if it is 1000+ USD that has decent picture quality.  Sure, it looks decent on the small screen but on a normal desktop monitor or a printout, it just looks too soft and watercolor painting-like.  The sensors are always too small on them.  The zoom just makes it look pixelated.  I can do 32x zoom and I can zoom into street signs with names which I can barely see and I can read the signs.  I had a Windows Phone but they quit supporting it, so I moved over to Android, and for me, it's just inferior, I just know how to use Windows and the UI is intuitive, unlike Android where it's much, much less elegant and way, way more bloated.  It's still better than IOS but not by that much.  I prefer Linux on the desktop way more than I do Windows but Windows have the application support. Android is so different it's like learning something completely new because it doesn't use the GNU userland.  I have custom-built a file server and built it from scratch with Debian minus the utilities because I am not going to custom code them and so if curious that is the level I am at.*

Comment: It sounds like your best option would be a ruggedized case with a built-in battery that can stay attached to the phone. I don't have specific recommendations in that area, but there are lots of options.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the use they get, most phones may not last the whole day.  Solutions

- Buy a phone with a larger battery
- Removed unused apps and dim the brightness
- Buy a battery pack such [this one](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07CZDXDG8).  You can charge the phone while its in your pocket.  If your phone has fast charge, it could be fully charged in 2 hours or less.  A 10000mAH one will charge your phone twice.  You can charge it when you are having a break.

  [image]

Comment: "You can charge it when you are having a break"  I actually have a battery pack.  I do not use it.  I do not take breaks because A) where to? and B) waste of time.  I do not get pay hourly but rather base on my results.  I get better numbers, I get pay more.  I take an lunch break during prime time would screw that up.

The phone is quite dim with the screen.  The only thing open is Firefox or Kiwi.

"Buy a phone with a larger battery"  Is there any phone which is design for the winter which has insulation to prevent it form during so fast?

Comment: If I have downtime* then I typically move to an different area than I would have to use navigation but I than tend to drop the phone and so I can not have any cable plug into it.